# How to set column names using Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I tried to give the name to columns in python using pandas, the problem is my data has 52 columns and I want to set a name only for the first 3 columns, what should I do?

[Here's what my data looks like after df = pd.read_csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0QLIZ.png)

Comment: Please [do not post images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) of your data. You can include [code that creates a dataframe or the output of `print(df)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) (or of a few rows and columns that allow to reproduce the example)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [the rename method](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html)

```
df.rename(columns={0: 'x', 1: 'y', 2: 'z'}, inplace=True)
```

Comment: Should be `{0: 'x', 1: 'y', 2: 'z'}`

Comment: Yes, thanks. You are right.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, I had tried but it doesn't work